# Symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony, get, routes

I have the following action:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/customer/shubausers")
 */


class UsersController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/users", name="customer_developers_users_get")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
```

When I try to access `http://artelfreelancedb.local/app_dev.php/customer/shubausers/users`, I am redirected to `http://artelfreelancedb.local/app_dev.php/auth/login`
and I dont know why. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please dump your `security.yml` file.

Comment: thanks ))) I forgot, I solved

Comment: Fixed minor grammatical issues.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony redirects you to the login page if the route you're trying to access is protected by the firewall. Open your *security.yml* file and make sure that the section **access_control** looks like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

You can learn how to configure the firewall properly here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html